# Background Property Not Working

Tags: html, css, background

Hey guys I just set up a new project in sublime. I am trying to set a div to have a background color as black.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my css:

```
.header {
background: blue;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Im sure there is just something really basic I am not understanding but this is irritating me sooooo much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `html`'s `height` to `100%` as well.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
</div>
```